# Increase padding betwen last word and page number in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

Are there any parameters which allow to set a padding between the last word of a figure in the list of figures and the page number. I have the problem below, and I have not been able to find any solution in the documentation.

[image: Issue with padding]

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would rather use a shorter title for the caption, at best with `\caption[short title]{long title}`

Comment: replace `2014` in the `[..]` "toc" title optional argument to `\caption` by some `{\protect\linebreak[4] 2014}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say, which document class you are using.  Most document classes typeset the page number in TOC, LOT, LOF, etc. in a box of width `\@pnumwidth`.  For example, `article.cls` uses

```
\newcommand\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
```

Try increasing this box using in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2em} % Maybe needs adjustment!
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you Boris, this worked perfectly. For the record, in case is useful for someone else in the future, I was using a report class.